# Why us Spring security password (instead of hash) baked into the documentation and code?

Tags: spring, spring-security, password-protection, password-hash

Why do Spring Security [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/appendix/database-schema.html#_user_schema) and [implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html#getPassword()) rely on password and not password hash?

Isn't it a major security issue, that might cause issues in many products? Thanks.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, the fact that it says `getPassword` doesn't mean it actually **is** the password. What it is depends on the `PasswordEncoder` in use.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks. [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html). It could have been named differently, explicitly targeting the real intention, like `passEnc`, or `passwordEncoded`. Also, they could have linked to the `PasswordEncoder` doc.

Comment: `getPassword` returns whatever you decided it to be when you build your `UserDetails`object. Most commonly you will set it to return whatever you have saved in your password field in the database. But if you have actively selected to store your passwords in your database in plain text by explicitly defining a `NoopPasswordEncoder` then yes it will return passwords in plain text. But that is very bad practice, most define the password encoder to be something that actually hashes the password, and then `getPassword` will return what you have stored.

Comment: And to use what? Maybe it is a secret, not a password, maybe it isn't encoded, maybe it is. Maybe it is a binary certificate that doesn't need anything. Also why should the fact that something might be encrypted reflected in the name of a property?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is wrong. The fact that something is called `getPassword` or the field `password` doesn't mean it isn't encrypted.

By default passwords are hashed using BCrypt in Spring Security. This is done through the `BCryptPasswordEncoder`. So what is stored (if anything is stored!) depends on the actual `PasswordEncoder` in use, next to ofcourse the authentication mechanism in use (for instance if you use X509 this would be empty).